# Read multiple files by passing them in argv[1]

Tags: c++, argv

This might be a basic question, but I am new to C++, so I would appreciate your understanding.

What I am trying to do is to read files from a folder and pass one of them at a time in argv[1], get some results from that file, write them in an output file specified in argv[2], then the same for the next file, and so on.

I guess it has something to do with pointers but I am not sure how to fix this.

Thank you for any input!

Here is what I have so far:

```
vector<string> getFilenames(string folder)
{
    vector<string> names;
    string search_path = folder + "/*.*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFile(search_path.c_str(), &fd);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
           // read all (real) files in current folder
           // , delete '!' read other 2 default folder . and ..
               if (!(fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
            names.push_back(fd.cFileName);
           }
        } while (::FindNextFile(hFind, &fd));
        ::FindClose(hFind);
    }

   return names;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    ofstream fileout(argv[2], ios::out | ios::app);
    int a, b, c;

    vector<string> filenames = getFilenames("folder path");
    istringstream iss;

    for (int i = 0; i < filenames.size(); i++) {
        iss.str(filenames[i]);
        iss >> argv[1];
        if (readFile(a, b, c, argv[1]) == 0) {

            /* do something */
        }
    }

    fileout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how somebody would use your program?  For example, `your-program a.txt folder-b`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `main.cpp filename.txt output.txt`

Comment: The problem is that after reading the first file, the next file seems to ''point'' to the contents of the previous file.

Answer (score 2):

I want to complete @Florian Klemme but I cannot comment.

There is a little example of how to iterate through command line parameters :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    for (auto i = int{0}; i < argc; ++i) {
        // do something with argv[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO `auto i = int{0};` is an obfuscated way to write `int i = 0;`.

Comment: Yeah of course, but using auto forces the programmer to initialize his variable.
For example you could write `int i;` but not `auto i;`

Comment: Keep in mind `argv[0]` is the programs name, so you might want your `int i` start at 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your problem is but maybe this little example can help as a starting point. It shows how you can

- Iterate though files in a directory (you need C++17 though)
- Read some number from a file
- Write to another file

Hopefully you can add the rest with no problem. :)

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string input_dir = argv[1];
    std::string output_file = argv[2];

    std::ofstream out(output_file);

    // Iterate over files in directory
    for(auto& file : fs::directory_iterator(input_dir)) {
        std::ifstream in(file.path());
        // In this example, read a integer number from the current file
        if (int i; in >> i) {
            std::cout << "Read " << i << " from " << file << std::endl;
            // ... and write it to the output file.
            out << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had to use though `namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;`. It seems that `file` returns the whole directory together with the file name. How can I retrieve only the file name as a string? For example, `input1.txt` instead of `C:\...\...\input1.txt`.

Comment: Try `file.filename()`. See here for more information: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path (scroll down, there are a lot of functions you can use)